# How does SuperDuper actually work?

Tags: mac, backup, rsync, superduper

I need to take a (full) bootable backup of my MBP and I see that most people use SuperDuper to do that.

Having rsync and similar tools native on Mac OS, I was wondering **how SuperDuper actually work** and if I can have a **similar results with some of those other tools**?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know programs like Carbon copy Cloner use rsync (or used to) but SuperDuper uses its own proprietary algorithm.
I bought SuperDuper as it's reputed to make a particularly good job of the Mac OS file metadata.  See MacWorld's Review http://www.macworld.com/article/50498/2006/04/superduper2.html